# Connect4 with MiniMax Algorithm in P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, minimax

I have been trying to learn Minimax algorithm and made a successful unbeatable Tic-Tac-Toe AI in p5.js, but decided to take it a step further and instead create Connect4. I've been doing quite well so far, the code works and when AI is told to choose a random spot it does it, however when I've tried to apply the minimax algorithm instead it would either break completely or only choose the next available spot in one column, then move to the next and repeat the process.

Not entirely sure why, but my guess is that the issue is with the minimax loop itself, I've tried playing around with it but nothing else worked.

I am keen to find the right direction on how to fix this issue as I'm really enjoying Minimax and was trying to apply the pruning method to enhance the algorithms speed.

Code is too long so I've put it on [pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/bXCbVSX6)

Here's the extract of my MiniMax initialisation (starts line 201):

```
  bestScore = -Infinity;
  for (let x = 0; x < 6; x++ ) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
      if (playable[x].k != -1) {
        if (board[playable[x].k][playable[i].i] == '') {
          board[playable[x].k][playable[i].i] = ai;

          let score = minimax(board, 0, -Infinity, Infinity, true);

          board[playable[x].k][playable[i].i] = '';

          a = playable[x].k
          b = playable[i].i

          if (score > bestScore) {
              bestScore = score;
              bestMove = { a , b };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your basic suggestion is wrong. You don't need 2 nested loops to iterate through the board, like at tic-tac-toe. You just have to iterate through the columns, because it is only possible to select a column rather than a filed.

Comment: But I also have to iterate through rows otherwise minimax will only predict next 7 turns only. I think

Comment: No, you've a recursive algorithm. The depth of the recursion does not depend on the loops. The loop evaluates the number of possibilities in 1 turn. There are not more than 7 possibilities in one turn, but the recursion depth can be up to 6*7. Furthermore, this huge maximum recursion depth, will make a perfectly working algorithm incredible slow.

Comment: I'm very sure that you've to start with `minimax(..., false);`, because after the computer follows the human turn.

Comment: Note at tic-tac-toe there are 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 = 362880 different possibilities. At connect 4 there are (7^35)*6*5*4*3*2*1 different possibilities

Comment: I am awake hence why I wanted to use pruning. To reduce the times, I will take into account what you said and try implement it. Thank you

Comment: so i've made your fixes, and it does not Error anymore, and i can fill up the entire board and force a "tie" without issues, however, AI only plays the very first column then the next then the one after. It never attempts to block or play differently... Any suggestions on why that is??

I've made the loop only occur 7 times and fixed the `minimax(...., false)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204674/discussion-between-d3v-and-rabbid76).

Comment: Alright after digging through my code, I realised it wasn't updating `available` table so it didn't account for changes it made, also made a stupid mistake of AI thinking its playing every turn. So on minimising it would `= ai` instead of `=human` this fixed the above issue, but the AI is still quite stupid. Does block plays but its rare and can be beaten very easily. Any suggestions?